# How to fix dynamic height for individual cells as UIautodimensions is not working

Tags: ios, swift4.1

I am creating a wall page like twitter or Facebook in which user can post on the wall it can include image and just text. So based on the content the cell's heights must change, if the post is of one line the row height must be appropriate.

I tried using UITableViewAutomaticDimensions, but its not working with my code please do help me.

```
import UIKit

class wallPageViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var tableOfApps : UITableView?
var appNames: [String]? = []
var apps: [wallPageModel]?
var dynamic_height : CGFloat = 150.0
var addPost : UITextField?
var readMore : UITextView?


func loadTableOfApps(){

    //appNames = ["jkbajdba", "abfajfb", "akjbfkjag", "ahbfkajf" ]

    let provider = wallPageProvider()
    apps = provider.getApps()

    let tableHeight = view.frame.size.height


    tableOfApps = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 60, width: 300, height: tableHeight))
    tableOfApps!.delegate = self
    tableOfApps!.dataSource = self
    tableOfApps?.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none


    //self.tableOfApps?.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    //self.tableOfApps?.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    print("load table of apps")

    view.addSubview(tableOfApps!)

}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadTableOfApps()
    loadAddPost()

    tableOfApps?.estimatedRowHeight = 150.0
    tableOfApps?.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 232/255, green: 234/255, blue: 246/255, alpha: 1.0)




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func loadAddPost(){
    addPost = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 300, height: 30))
    addPost?.placeholder = "Stay safe, post a tip!"
    addPost?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    addPost?.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
    addPost?.autocapitalizationType = .none
    view.addSubview(addPost!)

    addPost?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(writeComment), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)


}




func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print("app coun\(apps!.count)")
    return apps!.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    var cell : wallModelTableViewCell?

    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? wallModelTableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = wallModelTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    let app = apps![indexPath.row]//reading the array of data hence provider

    //association of provider and view
    //this is the processs from where view can read the data from provide

    cell!.iconImageLabel!.image = app.icon
    cell!.titleLabel!.text = app.title
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


    cell!.commentsLabel?.image = app.comments_Label
    cell?.commentsLabel?.center = CGPoint(x: tableView.frame.size.width/2, y: dynamic_height-20)

    cell?.likeButtonLabel?.image = app.likeButton
    cell?.likeButtonLabel?.center = CGPoint(x: (tableView.frame.size.width/2)-130, y: dynamic_height-20)
    /*cell?.likeButtonLabel?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.leftAnchor, constant: 50)*/

    cell!.feedTextLabel!.text = app.feedText
    cell?.feedTextLabel?.sizeToFit()//so that it can expand the data more than two lines
    cell?.feedTextLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


    //Limiting UIlabel to 125 characters
    if (cell?.feedTextLabel?.text.count)! > 125{
        /*
        let index = cell?.feedTextLabel?.text.index((cell?.feedTextLabel?.text.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 125)
        cell?.feedTextLabel?.text = cell?.feedTextLabel?.text.substring(to: index!)
        cell?.feedTextLabel?.text = cell?.feedTextLabel?.text.appending("...")*/
        //cell?.feedTextLabel?.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "...readmore")
    }


    cell?.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
    cell?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    cell?.titleLabel?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    tableOfApps?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    tableOfApps?.backgroundView?.isOpaque = false

    tableOfApps!.estimatedRowHeight = 150.0
    tableOfApps!.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension


    print("table view cell for row")

    /*let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer  = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector( self.labelAction(gesture:)))
    cell?.feedTextLabel?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    cell?.feedTextLabel?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    tap.delegate = self as! UIGestureRecognizerDelegate*/

    return cell!

}

/*@objc func labelAction(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){

}*/

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    print("height for row")
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 150.0
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



 // MARK: - Navigation
 @objc func writeComment(){
 let addComment = addCommentViewController()
 navigationController?.pushViewController(addComment, animated: true)
 }
/*
 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
 // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */

}
```

I want each row must have dynamic height as the content is provided by the user if the content contains 150 characters the height of the cell must be 200+ if content contains less than 125 characters the height must be as adequate to read.

Comment: What do your constraints look like(I'm making the assumption that you are using constraints)?

Comment: Check with the constraints in the cell, see if your storyboard has any error message

Comment: I suggest you to use UIStackView inside UITableViewCell. Checkout this https://medium.com/@alekkania/expandable-cells-with-stack-view-54c2c5cc8582

Comment: Actually I am not using storyboard I am trying to get the dynamic cell height programmatically

Comment: @AatishMolasi no actually I am mot using any constraints, an I want to get it done programmatically by not using the storyboard

Comment: Automatic dimensions only work when you're using constraints

Comment: @AatishMolasi I am new to iOS development would you guide me how to do that?

Comment: This would be a good start https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells